# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in D:\xampp\htdocs\IKM\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:91

```
function db_pconnect()
{
    if ($this->port != '')
    {
        $this->hostname .= ':'.$this->port;
    }

    return @mysql_pconnect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
}
```

Comment: What version of `php` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function has been removed as of PHP 7.0 and deprecated in PHP 5.5. Chances are you're using PHP 7.0.

To fix this, you need to use either the mysqli extension, or the PDO extension.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
I've changed msql into mysqli and it works